# T-SQL: How to selectively filter out duplicates from temp table

Tags: t-sql

I have a result set in a temp table that is the result of some complicated joins and need to know the best way to filter rows that have the same duplicate AccountId/HealthPlanId (shown below).

```
select * from #HealthPlans
```

And the contents are as follows:

```
AccountId  MemberId  HealthPlanId  RankNo
101273     47570     5215          1
101273     47570     2187          2
101273     55551     5179          3
160026     48102     5620          1
160026     48446     5620          2
```

In this scenario RankNo, which is not a value computed by my original query, is a db column that ranks member/healthPlan where there is more than one member/healthPlan combination on a given account.

In the case of account 101273, I have the same member (47570) with 3 separate health plans (5215, 2187, 5179). That's fine. I want to rank the health plans.

However, for accountId  160026, I have healthPlanId: 5620 listed twice but with different memberId's. I need to keep either of these member id's and discard the other (it doesn't matter which I keep since I'm only interested in Ranking the HealthPlanId).

Basically, an account should only have a row for each unique health plan. However, duplicate memberId's is OK and should be ranked as long as the HealthPlanId differs.

In other words, select rows from #HealthPlans such that the following is the result set:

```
AccountId  MemberId  HealthPlanId  RankNo
101273     47570     5215          1
101273     47570     2187          2
101273     55551     5179          3
160026     48102     5620          1
```

There's no need to show the original joins because this is basically a simplification of my original issue.

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method using a window function:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (AccountId int,  MemberId int,  HealthPlanId int,  RankNo int)
INSERT @tab VALUES
(101273,47570,5215,1),
(101273,47570,2187,2),
(101273,55551,5179,3),
(160026,48102,5620,1),
(160026,48446,5620,2)




SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.AccountId, t.HealthPlanId ORDER BY t.RankNo) rn, t.*
    FROM @tab t
    ) t2
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

Your particular query might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hp.AccountId, hp.HealthPlanId ORDER BY hp.RankNo) rn, hp.*
    FROM #HealthPlans hp
    ) hp2
WHERE hp2.rn = 1
```